# Mailgun emails are rejected everywhere but receive on Gmail

Tags: php, laravel, mailgun

I have implement **mailgun** in laravel it will work perfect when send mail to any gmail account

But it will not work when send mail to other than **gmail** account and not receive any error regarding this

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your mailgun domain has dkim and spf records exists. After that, please lookup mailgun logs, mailgun is logging all sending emails. Fail or success.

PS: please ask question in your question next time.
Have a nice job